# Does storm support ha host, e.g. for the nimbus host?

Tags: apache-storm, high-availability, nimbus

If so, from which version, does storm support this?　I want to know this because I want to upgrade my storm version(now my storm version is 0.10.0).

Answer (score 1):

High availability for Nimbus was introduced in Storm 1.0.0 (see https://storm.apache.org/2016/04/12/storm100-released.html)

However, even for prior Storm versions, missing HA for Nimbus was not a critical issue, because a failing Nimbus does not affect running topologies. The only problem if Nimbus is down is, that no interaction with the cluster is possible from outside (eg, submitting new topologies etc.).

Workers are HA too, ie, supervisors can restart failing workers. Supervisors are not HA -- however, the task they host will be redistributed automatically to other supervisors if one supervisor fails.